# How do I remove NULL values from a query result in SQL

Tags: sql

I am joining two tables `Wands` and `Wands_Property` to get specific information. In my `SELECT` statement, I have this statement

```
SELECT 
    Wands.id, Wands_Property.age, Wands.coins_needed,
    CASE
        WHEN Wands_Property.is_evil = 0 
           THEN Wands.power
    END
FROM Wands
```

Right so, if the `is_evil` column in the `Wands_Property` table is 0, then I want to display the power column from the `Wands` table.

However the result displays the rows that meet the condition, and ones that don't meet the condition display NULL. I do not want the rows that display Null to appear in my result at all. What can I do? Thanks

Comment: Step 1 : `JOIN` the tables.

Comment: They are joined, I just left that part out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `where` clause to filter rows:

```
SELECT Wands.id, Wands_Property.age, Wands.coins_needed,
       Wands.power
FROM Wands
WHERE Wands_Property.is_evil = 0
```

Comment: I don't work with SQL much, so I am seeing this syntax for the first time. We don't need `join` to use 2 tables in `select` ?

Comment: This was the answer. So obvious once it was revealed. Thanks!